# How can I check if a windows service is installed using path of executable?

Tags: c#, windows-services

How can I check if a windows service is installed using just the executable path?
I checked the ServiceController class - it lets you use service name and display name
but not the executable name to verify.

I only have the executable's FullName available for use in my code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options.

1. WMI. The Win32_Service class's PathName property has the executable command line (so includes parameters).
2. Iterate through the registry

Comment: Too cumbersome. Thanks anyways.